What statistical test to compare survival curves for dependent data?
I'm currently doing time to event analysis for a cohort of participants. Each participant completed two different diagnostic tests for the same virus, and they did these every day for a week.
Basically- I am showing the survival curves for time to negative test result. I am comparing the curves of test A and test B. So each participant is represented in both groups. In the photo, blue is test A and red is test B.
My question is- is there a statistical test to compare these curves? The log-rank test has an assumption of independence, which I believe my comparison violates. So I am not sure where to go from here.
Survival Curves

The survival curve for test A (blue curve) starts at a value below 1 (about 0.8) at time = 0. Please explain how that came to be, as usual survival models start with a survival value of 1 at time = 0 for all groups.

@EdM We refer to the first day of testing as Day 0. Some of them tested negative on Day 0.

Thanks. Please now edit the question to say more about the specific hypothesis that you want to test. Do you have further information about when the virus was actually cleared, or just about when each of the tests gave a negative result? In the extreme, you could have one test that always gives a positive result and a second test that always gives a negative result. There certainly would be a big difference between the two tests, but neither would be very useful. Please edit the question to say more about what you are hoping to learn here, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.
